# Which emulator/avd is best suited for pocket design

Tags: android, mobile-development

I have an android application which I would like to design for the pocket phone and I noticed that the emulators differ in sizes when setting up avd. Do I create an avd that is the size of the pocket phone and which size is it? How do I create an avd to do pocket design testing on it?

Comment: the pocket phone? Is that a term for small phones or a concrete product?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing has a table with different configurations and what size / density they represent. And https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html lists how many of those size exist. Then in http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html#createavd dialog select it. The 2.7" QVGA is the small one in the table top left. You can btw preview your design without an AVD https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/FJv7Pym2HtZ